# Making checkbox when container is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div element containing a checkbox, when I click the div I want the checkbox to toggle.
I did this by assigning the following code to $(#div).click:

```
$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked"));
```

The problem now is that if the checkbox itself is clicked, the code above is still executed and thus the checkbox stays in the same state. 
How would I fix this?

Comment: Can you use a better selector than $(this).find... ?

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is bubbling up, you need to stop event propogation, one way is

```
$('#myDiv :checkbox').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

### Edit

In case you want to handle the event at div use this

```
$('div').click(function(e) {

    // check if the event was triggered by an input box
    if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT") {
        $(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked"));
    }

    // do something else 
    alert('hey there!');

});​
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/QnbhX/

Comment: Although the state of the checkbox is now "correct" this solution blocks all the code in the div.click event.
I used your code and pretty much made the checkbox toggle twice instead of once. Thanks

Comment: Agreed. Thats what it does. div.click never knows if the click was made if its done on checkbox. If you want it to know then there is a diferent way to do this.. updating

Answer (score 0):

onclick() of div element, attach a javascript function which toggles the checkbox output. Isn't that a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a better selector like :

```
$('#myDiv').find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked"));
```